# How to prevent rdiff-backup on cygwin from crashing?

Tags: windows-7, backup, cygwin, rdiff-backup

I'd like to employ rdiff-backup for backing up my user directory of my Windows 7 - 64 bits.

I use the following command line:

```
rdiff-backup -v5 /cygdrive/D/home/maxp /cygdrive/t/Backup/Users/maxp/home
```

(where T: is an USB disk, and the directory I want to back up is about 780Gb).

rdiff-backup runs for a while, but it always raises an exception before completing the backup.

I'm using the latest cygwin 64 bits, with an rdiff-backup v1.3.3 built by me. Since it halted for EBUSY I patched "rpath.py" with few line to retry on busy files for a while. Despite of this the backup crashes for a missing file. Oddly enough the file is one temporary file created by rdiff-backup itself.

So my question is - is there something obvious (or less obvious) I am missing to operate successfully rdiff-backup on cygwin?

Thank you

--
MaxP